# Apache POI -- Excel function exits early, no error

Tags: java, apache-poi

I'm writing a web app that creates an Excel file that the user can download.  I thought there was something wrong with my file creation code, so I replaced it with something off of here that supposedly works.

When it reaches:

```
XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook();
```

it leaves the CreateExcel class without running the rest of the code or generating an error.

I'm using Apache POI 3.14 and developing on Netbeans.  I am completely baffled by this, and any help would be appreciated.

The relevant code:

Servlet entry:

```
else if (request.getParameter("formType").equalsIgnoreCase("downloadExcel")) {
        String filePath = "";
        try {
            ThreadB b = new ThreadB();
            int viewId = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("viewId"));
            b.tc = DatabaseUtil.getClassDetails(viewId);
            b.classList = DatabaseUtil.getClassRoster(viewId);
            b.start();

            synchronized (b) {
                try {
                    b.wait();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
                    out.write(TrainingRegistrationServlet.stackTraceToString(e));
                    out.close();
                }
                filePath = b.filePath;
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException ex) {
            PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
            out.write(TrainingRegistrationServlet.stackTraceToString(ex));
            out.close();
        }
        sendFile(response, filePath);

    }
```

Thread:

```
class ThreadB extends Thread {

    String filePath;
    TrainingClass tc = null;
    List<Registrant> classList = null;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        synchronized (this) {
            try {
                filePath = CreateExcel.createRoster(tc, classList);
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(ThreadB.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

CreateExcel class:

```
package org.bcso.com.TrainingRegistration.util;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFCell;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;

import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

import org.bcso.com.TrainingRegistration.data.Registrant;
import org.bcso.com.TrainingRegistration.data.TrainingClass;

public class CreateExcel {

    public CreateExcel(TrainingClass tc, List<Registrant> rosterList) {

    }

    public static String createRoster(TrainingClass tc, List<Registrant> rosterList) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
        String excelFileName = "C:/tmp/Test.xlsx";//name of excel file
        String sheetName = "Sheet1";//name of sheet

        XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook();
        XSSFSheet sheet = wb.createSheet(sheetName);

        for (int r = 0; r < 5; r++) {
            XSSFRow row = sheet.createRow(r);
            for (int c = 0; c < 5; c++) {
                XSSFCell cell = row.createCell(c);
                cell.setCellValue("Cell " + r + " " + c);
            }
        }

        FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(excelFileName);

        wb.write(fileOut);
        fileOut.flush();
        fileOut.close();
        return excelFileName;
    }
}
```

Comment: It would help you to find a helper by reducing the code to the minimum reproducible code - read the instructions here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. It's good that you provided a lot of context, but is really *this all* relevant?

Comment: Sorry.  Always of the opinion of "better to have it and not need it than need it and not have it."

Comment: NO, no when asking for help. Create an absolutely minimal program which still have the same error. Maybe this activity itself will help you find the root cause. And if not, others are not bothered with your business logic and with a lot of irrelevant mess. (And do not apologize, just change your question :) )

Comment: I appreciate that.  I'll remember it for my next question.

Comment: Wrong attitude. Remember it earlier, i.e. for fixing THIS question...

Comment: Who are you?   Is this your function, making sure that people's format and code samples are correct instead of helping find the issue?

Comment: Well, I could have answered you just with "TLDR". Instead, I was trying to advice you *how to increase the probability* that someone will spend their time with *your* problem. And yes, I do not bother reading **unnecessary long** questions...

Comment: And I think I said I appreciated your suggestion.  However, I don't know WHERE in the code the issue is, if I'm doing something wrong in other areas that may be causing the issue I'm describing.  The people who answer with "TLDR" aren't usually the people who genuinely want to help others out, anyway.

Comment: LOL....so you downvote me.  I do believe you're moving in the "petty" category.

Comment: Have you *read* the link in my comment? There is quite a good guide *how* to do it. People who are not willing to spend time to make it easier for the possible helpers do not  usually deserve any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turned out that I WAS getting an error, it was just being reported very slowly.  I had mismatched jars for Apache POI.

If anyone else has this issue, you can get the correct version of the jars via a link at: https://poi.apache.org/overview.html